# Sharepoint: change dropdown arrow in Welcome control (wssuc:Welcome)

Tags: sharepoint

I'm trying to change the color of the dropdown arrow in the Sharepoint 2010 Welcome control, that looks like this:

```
<wssuc:Welcome id="IdWelcome" runat="server" EnableViewState="false">
```

I've found the classes to color everything else, but can't change the little down arrow. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do so with the help of css by hiding the arrow in the img-tag and showing your arrow-image as background-image in the span-tag (which surrounds the img-tag):

```
/* Your arrow as background-image */
DIV > SPAN > SPAN.s4-clust.ms-viewselector-arrow
{
    background-image:url('your_arrow_url.gif');
}

/* Hide original arrow-image */
DIV > SPAN > SPAN.s4-clust.ms-viewselector-arrow > IMG
{
    visibility:hidden;
}
```

You have to use the path mentioned above so your breadcrumb arrows won't be affected.

Answer (score 1):

Change 14\TEMPLATE\CONTROLTEMPLATES\Welcome.ascx. Add ArrowImageUrl attribute to SharePoint:PersonalActions control (or equivalent).

- Jesse
  Jester Software Inc.